# Call operator by name

Tags: go

What is the Go equivalent of, for example, Python's [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/operator.html) package for calling builtin operators by name?

Meaning, how can I do something like:

```golang
func f(op func(int, int)bool, a int, b int)
    ...
    if op(a, b) {
        ...

f(operators.LessThan, 1, 2) // true
```

Stated otherwise, how to write a function that takes in what basic operator to apply as a function argument?

Comment: There isn't one. You'd need to write those (one-line) functions yourself.

Comment: @Adrian that's a valid answer, but not sure if the question deserves a downvote.

Comment: @Tommy I agree.  For your answer, there isn't one. Operators in Golang are not  functions as some other languages such as Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't assume language X has any equivalent for feature Y in language Z. Also you should write/design code for the language you're using rather than designing as if it was another language and then translating line-by-line or function-by-function.

As comments mentioned, operators are builtin in Go with no operator overloading or functional equivalents. If you haven't already you should take the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/) and read the [Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec) to see what Go does have.

If you really want/need to do something like you ask this is one way:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Compare func(int, int) bool

func DoCompare(cmp Compare, a, b int) bool {
    return cmp(a, b)
}

var (
    CmpLessThan           = func(a, b int) bool { return a < b }
    CmpLessThanOrEqual    = func(a, b int) bool { return a <= b }
    CmpGreaterThan        = func(a, b int) bool { return a > b }
    CmpGreaterThanOrEqual = func(a, b int) bool { return a >= b }
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(DoCompare(CmpLessThan, 1, 2))
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uELm4RAujAI).

Normally if something like this is needed, instead of multiple comparison functions, a single compare function is used that returns <0, 0, or, >0 (e.g. -1, 0, +1) for less-than, equal, greater-than. For example, [`big.Int.Cmp`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Cmp).

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2023 / Go with Generics**

Powered by Go generics, I made a new package to do this at [github.com/tawesoft/golib/v2/operator](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/tawesoft/golib/v2/operator):

For your example use case,

```golang
import "tawesoft/golib/v2/operator"

...

f := operator.LT[int] // less than
f(1, 2) // true
```

---

**Old answer**

I needed the same thing - basic operators as first-class functions in Go - and ended up writing a template and a bit of Python to generate my own.

I've packaged it up into a single well-tested Go module, called `operator` after the Python module.

Hope this helps!

**Go Get:**

```
go get -u tawesoft.co.uk/go/operator
```

**Examples:**

```
operator.Boolean.Not(true) == false
operator.Boolean.Nary.Any(false, true, true, false) == true
operator.Int.Binary.Add(1, 2) == 3
```

In your case:

```
f(operator.Int.Binary.Lt, 1, 2)
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer here. Not sure why you (actually and I and every answer so far!) are all downvoted. YoU CAnT dO ThAt

Comment: some people *really* hate functional programming in Go :P